# Replace edit and delete html buttons with image icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic

In the jsfiddle below everything works perfectly.  I am trying however to replace the edit and delete with edit.ico and delete.ico.  Both of these icon files will be in the same directory. I have tried so many approaches I have lost track. Pretty new to jQuery and Javascript but I have cobbled together an application that I use based on this jsfiddle.

`Please see:` http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/EfRWZ/2/

I would appreciate any help anybody can give.

Comment: Please show relevant code in question itself, along with expected results. I don't see anything in demo related to icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to replace buttons with icons. Here's a fork of your JSFiddle with edit and delete icons.

http://jsfiddle.net/colinwhitmarsh/2nt3vc2r/1/

In the top of the HTML you can see there's a `<link/>` tag to load Google's Material Icons https://design.google.com/icons/. These are free and easy to use. I recommend them if you're unfamiliar with icons and want to experiment.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

To include the icons, I changed the `<button>` tags to `<i>`, added `class="material-icons"`, and changed the text to the name of the icon. Checkout design.google.com/icons to find the names of other icons you want to use.

**Changed**

```
<button onclick='deleteRow(" + rowID + ")'>Delete</button>
```

**To**

```
<i class='material-icons' onclick='deleteRow(" + rowID + ")'>delete</i>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for introducing me to the magic of Google Material Icons.  That is so awesome.  Less coding worries, and no need to edit graphics to fit your color scheme.  Awesome...  Thanks again!